# Can pizza be called a delicacy?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

Can pizza be called a *delicacy*? I looked up the word *delicacy* in a dictionary, and it does seem to apply to a pizza too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You should add the dictionary definition that you looked up, and also explain why you're unsure that the definition doesn't apply to pizza.

Comment: No. I'm interested to know why you think that pizza would be a delicacy. Have you ever had pizza?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Generally,  no.

"Delicacy" is a term used to refer to expensive, rarely-eaten, and generally considered "special" foods. Pizza, by contrast, is a food that is cheap, frequently eaten, and generally considered common or base; it is basically the opposite of a delicacy.

That said, it's possible that a particular sort of pizza might be considered a delicacy, depending on what it's been topped with - a pizza topped with things like gold leaf and caviar certainly would be considered a delicacy, for instance.

It might also be possible for pizza to be a "local delicacy", whose special nature is derived from only being available in a particular area, such as the deep-dish Chicago pizza.

Answer (score 1):

Does “mouth-watering”, “delicious”, “cheap and cheerful”, “disgusting” apply to pizza? That’s not a matter of the dictionary definition alone, it’s also a matter of your taste and of the specific pizza. For each of the words I’ve had examples of pizzas where the word would fit.

Calling pizza “a delicacy” would be unusual. Either the pizza is truly outstanding, or the person eating it has never had pizza before. Note that “delicious” and “a delicacy” are close but different, while “delicate” is quite different.